# With a user specified by IP address, why I can't connect to mysql server remotely?

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I am trying to set mysql server on an office computer to allow only for my computer at home to be able to connect to the mysql server.

I created a user on the mysql server. The user is specified by IP address(XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) of my home computer.

```
Login name: myname

Limit to Hosts Matching: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

and also, in Administrative Roles tab, I added `DBManager` to this user.

and then, I tested this connection from my home computer using mysql workbench, and I got this error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at ---.---.---.---:3306 with user myname

Host '???-???-???-???-???.abc.defg.hi.jk' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

`---.---.---.---`: IP address of the computer that has mysql server.

`???-???-???-???-???.abc.defg.hi.jk`: I am not sure about this. Looks like some gate way name.

Comment: are you trying to connect to SQL server, or MySQL server?   also, you're supposed to grant permissions explicitly for your username and host. i.e. ```grant <whatever permissions> on <database>.* to <username>@<host>```  where host is the fdqn

Comment: @ewong sorry, it's MySQL server. And, I have granted permissions to the user on the workbench. I added `DBManager` to this user. I fixed it in OP, too.